# PHP Object from Multiple tables- Performance

Tags: php, mysql, object

My boss has given me the task of building a better formed object than what we have currently.  The company has been working with a spaghetti pot for the last few years and I've been brought in to clean it up.

I'm trying to get a PHP Class of users such that when instantiated it will look like this:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
$user->firstname;
$user->lastname;
$user->haircolor;
$user->eyecolor;
$user->homephone;
```

And so on and so forth.  Now, if they were all on one table, but in order to get all this data, I'll have to query several tables.  Sure, fine.  But if I'm defining a class to get all the user information, several queries, or a massive join will have to be called in the constructor. Right?

Is there a better way to do this?  The goal is to organize the code better with the best load time.  The boss specifically wants to have the variables and not the functions.  I'm not sure what the reason behind it is, he just asked me to do this.

So, my specific question is, is there an easier, faster way to do this than by calling multiple queries and/or using an enormous JOIN?

Comment: Can you do all the work in the database? You should be able to create a VIEW which has all the information you want. That way, you just need to do one query, for the view, and the database takes care of all the joins for you. That said, I've no idea what the performance is like with a view compared to other ways of accessing the data.

Comment: If all the data is in different tables and you need it, you have to at some time fetch it. Either through queries or joins. If you don't want the load on the database, look into different cache options such as http://memcached.org/. You could either cache the entire object or the data returned from the database.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have work done in the constructor. Also, database interaction is not the `User`'s job, it's the job of some sort of DataMapper object. And probably some sort of `UserFactory` to create user objects from the datamapper.

Comment: Well, I mean, I wouldn't be doing the work in the constructor, I'd be calling private functions within the constructor to define the class variables.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions.  At this point, we're really rushing towards getting this spaghetti pot launched, so we might just have to work on this later.  I'll present the boss with your ideas and I'll take the credit, sound good?  :-P  Hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User  {
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    public $creationdate;
    public $user_image;



    public static function find_all(){
        return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users");
    }

    public static function find_by_id($id=0){

        $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        //$found=$database->fetch_array($result_set);
        return !empty($result_array)?array_shift($result_array):FALSE;
    }

    public static function find_by_sql($sql=""){
        global $database;
        $result_set=$database->query($sql);
        //return $result_set;

        $object_array=array();
        while($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
            $object_array[]=self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $object_array;

    }






    private static function instantiate($record){
        //long form
        $object=new self;


        //dynamic
        foreach ($record as $attribute=>$value){
            if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
                $object->$attribute =$value;
            }
        }

        return $object;
    }

    private function has_attribute($attribute){
        //get_object_vars returns an associative array with all attributes
        $object_vars=get_object_vars($this);
        //we will return true or false
        return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
    }



        //dynamically add the public class variable and it will automatically assign the value
//if you are joining the queries than it will also work
//and your code will work here
//$user = new User();
//$user->firstname;
//$user->lastname;
//$user->haircolor;
//$user->eyecolor;
//$user->homephone;



}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from my comment, you could implement a kind of lazy loading for your database information. Say for example that you have a user and that a user can be connected to other users as friends. But if you don't need the friends every time you create a User object (this also allows you to use getFriends() multiple times on the object but only fetch the data once from the database):

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $friends;

    public function __construct($id) {
        // If you have a caching solution, you can check the cache first
        // Load user from database, fetch and set id and name.
    }

    public function getFriends() {
        if ($this->friends != null) {
            return $this->friends;
        }

        // If you have a caching solution, you can check the cache first
        // Fetch friends from databse, set instance variable and return it
    }

    public function save() {
        // Save information to database and possibly cache
    }
}
```